# R3HAB's record label

Tags: electronic-music

I haven't found any clues about R3HAB's new label.

Did R3HAB leave Spinnin' Records and start releasing on his own, or is he still part of Spinnin' Records?

Comment: Can you pls add some detail about what sources you looked in for info on this, so others don't repeat searching what you already did ?

Answer (score 1):

From Spinnin' Records website, his last release, [*Sakura*](https://www.spinninrecords.com/releases/830-sakura/) is dated from Jun 13, 2016. I did not find any relase since this date exept a remix from another artist.

According to his Wikipedia page, he also works/worked for:

- [Revealed recordings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revealed_Recordings)
- [Protocol recordings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicky_Romero#Protocol_Recordings)
- [Wall Recordings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Afrojack#Wall_Recordings)

From his [website](http://www.djr3hab.com), his on tour right now, so probably not doing studio work, hence not related to a specific label.

**EDIT**: On his two last tracks, the references are **℗ 2016 R3HAB MUSIC** so he probably released them with his own label.

Comment: He actually released Icarus, and Everything (with Skytech) recently.